# CAS Spring - way to manage client session

Tags: java, spring, cas

I have a Cas-Server and a Client configured via Spring security.

I use `jquery.sessionTimeout` plugin for case when users session ends but user does not close a browser tab/window.

I need a way to manage session when user closes browser tab. I want to send request to Cas-Server on logout URL when user session is destroyed by application web server.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Seems to me you either want to make CAS server session expire on browser close, which you so can do use `cas.tgc.maxAge=-1`. Or you want to trigger some action during tab close, which is unfornuately very difficult if not even possible to do, see this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing`

Comment: is there a way to programatically delete CAS TGC cookie when session invalidate from spring?